# Sliding / rolling effect for comments

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to insert comments on my webpage, with a "sliding effect" so that each comment appears for a few seconds, then slides left to leave the place for another comment.

A webpage where you can see such effet is the following one: www.resto-in.fr (at the bottom of the page, in the white area, where it is written "Nos clients sont satisfaits".

Do you have any idea on how to make it? I don't even know the name of such effect.

Thank you very much for your help!

Paul

Comment: It's a jQuery slider/carousel. Please note that SO is not here to write code for you. Have a play with a jQuery Slider (there are many) and come back if you run into any issues. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term you are looking for is "carousel".  Bootstrap has a pretty good [carousel component](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel) built in, and I'm sure there are [plenty of others](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+carousel).